# Google plus is not parsing page data correctly

Tags: google-plus

My problem is that when i would like to share a url from my image uploading site on google+ then it is not displaying any image. 
The url would be this: http://picstore.eu/k/DSCF0802.jpg (Its not an advertising)
No images are displayed on g+.
On facebook its working... there are the images displayed without any problems. 
Could you help me what metatag i'm missing or what's wrong? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it. The problem was that the url ended with `something.jpg` and google plus recognized it as some image and for that reason it was not working...
Now i have changed the url to this, so i removed the extension: 
http://picstore.eu/k/DSCF0802
Now it's okay!

Answer (score 1):

You need schema.org metadata on the site, configure this using the [snippet tool](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/).  In your example, the following would probably fix your markup:

Add the following to your  tags:

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="DSCF0802.jpg adatai">
<meta itemprop="description" content="A picstore egy képfeltöltő aminek segítségével megoszthatod a képeidet másokkal">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://p1.picsto.re/DSCF0802.jpg">
```

You could also add the itemprop / content values directly into your HTML, but this is the easiest fix.

Comment: if you take a look at the source code of the site which i have linked then you see that these itemprob attributes are there in the html and it is not really working but i give it a try with these what you specified

Comment: Yeah, I had looked at it before: the itemprop attribute is there just not the content attribute.